# converting a ssize_t to string as double

Tags: c, size-t

```
char* sizeToStr(ssize_t size){
char* s = NULL;
if(size<=1023){
    sprintf(s,"%.1dB",(1.0*size));
    return s;
}
if(size<=1048575){
    sprintf(s,"%.1dK",(1.0*size)/1024);
    return s;
}
if(size<=1073741823){
    sprintf(s,"%.1dM",(1.0*size)/(1024*1024));
    return s;
}
sprintf(s,"%.1dG",(1.0*size)/(1024*1024*1024));
return s;
```

I tried to write a code that takes a `ssize_t` variable that represents a size of file in bytes and returns a string representing this number in a {B,KB,MB,GB} format. I want that if for example the file is q.abc...MB for example the string will be truncated in the first digit after the decimal point i.e. will be q.aMB.
this code is not working is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I mentioned it below

Comment: `%d` is for `int` values; use `%f` or variations for printing `double`.  Do you really have fractional bytes?

Comment: `%.1d` => `%.1f`. Check formats: http://www.mobidev.com/shalan/scanf_printf.htm

Comment: You need to actually allocate some space to write your strings into... you can't just copy a string to a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Dmitri thanks I figured it out